# Neo4j Cypher Group By

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (c:Criterion {id: 24}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(d:Decision)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(s:Skill) 
WHERE s.id <> c.id WITH c, s
```

How to continue the query in order to return for `c`: `s` and `count of each distinct s` ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to collect and count s at the same time, then UNWIND the collection back into individual rows if you want to continue with each individual s node.

```
MATCH (c:Criterion {id: 24}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(d:Decision)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(s:Skill) 
WHERE s.id <> c.id 
WITH c, collect(DISTINCT s) as skills, count(DISTINCT s) as count
UNWIND skills as s
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return each distinct `s` and its count:

```
MATCH (c:Criterion {id: 24})<-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(:Decision)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(s:Skill) 
WHERE s.id <> c.id
RETURN s, COUNT(*) AS cnt
```